# chrome.Wallpaper.setWallpaper // Using file URLs over web URLs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently making a Chrome App that is supposed to change the wallpaper of the chromebook device. My question is simple; how can I use file URLs, or, the directory of the extension, as the image that is being set?

Here's what I mean:

When you call chrome.wallpaper.setWallpaper(), it looks like this:

```
chrome.wallpaper.setWallpaper( {
  'url': 'website/linkToImage',
  'layout': 'CENTER_CROPPED',
  'filename': 'example'
}, function() {})
```

I have tried to set this to an Extension file url such as 'images/x.png', and even tried chrome.runtime.getURL('images/x.png'), but it doesn't allow it. What am I doing wrong? Any tips or info is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a `data URI` representation of the file?

Comment: How would I implement this? You are speaking of the 'data' argument, correct? I don't know much about data URIs but it's asking for binary-format, so I'm clueless.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs